# Series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(\alpha\cdot n+1)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

I know that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}\quad y\quad \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}
$$
I would like to know if there is a closed formula for $f(\alpha)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(\alpha\cdot n+1)^2}$, since $f(1)=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$ and $f(2)=\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}$. If so, how could I prove it, I have been trying with $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(3n+1)^2}$ but without success. As mentioned in a comment, the digamma function is related but I would like to see details or references of said property, if possible.

Comment: If $\psi(z)=\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$ (that is, $\psi$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)), then$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(\alpha n+1)^2}=\frac1{\alpha^2}\psi'\left(\frac1\alpha\right).$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Interesting, I will try to test that property you mention but it would be very helpful if you could comment or give some idea. Thank you.